# Spline interpolation problem akin to Bezier spline

Tags: interpolation, bezier-curve, spline

Given three pairwise distinct points $p_1, p_2, p_3 \in \mathbb{R}^2$, I'd like to find a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ with at least $f \in C^1$ such that 
$f(0) = p_1, f(1) = p_3, f'(1) = a$ for a given vector $a$ "pointing" inside the convex hull of $p_1, p_2, p_3$ s.t. 
$(p_2 - p_3) \cdot a \leq 0$ and $(p_1 - p_3) \cdot a \geq 0$. Furthermore $f(t)$ should stay inside the convex hull spanned by $p_1, p_2, p_3$ for all $t \in (0,1)$.

The above problem is very similar to the Bezier spline with the only difference of the specific prescription of a derivative at one of the end point $p_3$ which does not necessarily point in the direction $(p_2-p_3)$.

As I'm quite new to spline interpolation, I'd be very much indebted to any help regarding this problem.

Comment: Is it a good idea to try parabolic splines? Here is a reference: http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/hdb_spul/Splines.pdf

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just quickly glanced through your document. It seems to me, that a single parabolic spline does not work, because it lacks the necessary degrees of freedoms: E.g. the parabola could be fitted to interpolate both end-points and satisfy the derivative at $p_3$, however it does not necessarily stay within the convex hull of the three points.

Comment: Are you sure your equalities regarding dot products with $a$ are correct? I don't see how they imply "pointing inside". A picture would be a big help. If you want what I think you want, then it's only possible if the length of $a$ is within certain limits.